# Is it possible to have multiple listeners listening to the same queue using spring amqp

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We have 2 different applications which interact with each by sending messages. Is it possible to have multiple listeners listening to the same queue. May be we could pass some header while pushing the message to the queue and then on the basis of header, the message would arrive in a single consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; RabbitMQ doesn't work that way; unlike JMS, there is no notion of a message selector.

Each consumer needs its own queue and you use a routing key to tell the broker which queue to route the message to.